# How to set default controller inside n subfolder in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
-Myproject
  -application
    -controllers
     -subfolder1
        -subfolder2
            -subfolder3
              -subfolder(..n)
                 Controller.php
```

And need to set `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder(..n)/controller';
```

Comment: [Did you read the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories)?  Apparently you can't put the controller more than one level deep inside a sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the examples in the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories) it does not appear that you can put a Controller more than one level deep inside a subdirectory.

```
example.com/index.php/subdirectory/controller/function
```

I also don't think your route looks correct.  You would not have `home/` at the start of the route unless `"home"` is a controller or subdirectory name.  See [examples here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples).

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subdirectory/controller';
```

Comment: @Sparkey, I have corrected route and also found a solution and posted an answer. it works for me. can you please check if it is effective.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched and found in codeigniter 3 `system/core/Router.php` library file's method `_set_default_controller()` can not support default controller in subfolder. So i have overrided/ customized this method `_set_default_controller()` and now it supports n level subfolders and working fine for me.

I have created `application/core/MY_Router.php` with the below code to override this method `_set_default_controller()`

```
<?php
/**
 * Override Set default controller
 *
 * @author : amit 
 *
 * @return  void
 */
protected function _set_default_controller()
{   
    if (empty($this->default_controller))
    {
        show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
    }

    // Is the method being specified?
    $x = explode('/', $this->default_controller);
    $dir = APPPATH.'controllers'; // set the controllers directrory path
    $dir_arr = array();
    foreach($x as $key => $val){            
        if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$val)){
            // find out class i.e. controller
            if(file_exists($dir.'/'.ucfirst($val).'.php')){
                $class = $val; 
                if(array_key_exists(($key+1), $x)){
                    $method = $x[$key+1]; // find out method i.e. action
                }else{
                    $method = 'index'; // default method i.e. action
                }
            }else{
                // show error message if the specified controller not found
                show_error('Not found specified default controller : '. $this->default_controller); 
            }                
            break;               
        }
        $dir_arr[] = $val;
        $dir = $dir.'/'.$val;
    }
    //set directory
    $this->set_directory(implode('/', $dir_arr));

    $this->set_class($class);
    $this->set_method($method);

    // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
    $this->uri->rsegments = array(
        1 => $class,
        2 => $method
    );

    log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
}
?>
```

Now we can set default controller in `application/config/routes.php` like below

// without action method name

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subfoler1/subfoler2/subfolder3/subfolder(..n)/controller';
```

OR

// with action method name

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subfoler1/subfoler2/subfolder3/subfolder(..n)/controller/action';
```

If we will pass the action method name it will detect that method as action and if we will not pass action name then it will assume index as a action.